# Java: different output when scanning input with spaces or enters as delimiters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, println

I'm trying to get input from the user and print it to the console using Java 8 (IDE BlueJ, Windows 10). 
When printing the output there is a bug: the program prints Equation 2 twice instead of printing Equation 1 and Equation 2.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equations
{
        public static void main (String[] args)

    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

        System.out.println("This program solves a system of 2 linear equations");
        System.out.println("Enter the coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2");

        int a11 = scan.nextInt();
        int a12 = scan.nextInt();
        int a21 = scan.nextInt();
        int a22 = scan.nextInt();
        int b1 = scan.nextInt();
        int b2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Eq1: "+ a11 +"*x1+"+ a12 +"*x2="+ b1);
        System.out.println("Eq2: "+ a21 +"*x1+"+ a22 +"*x2="+ b2);

    }
}
```

this is the expected output:

> This program solves a system of 2 linear equations Enter the
>   coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2
>   **1 2 3 4 5 6**
>   Eq1: 1*x1+2*x2=5
>   Eq2: 3*x1+4*x2=6

And this is the output:

> This program solves a system of 2 linear equations Enter the
>   coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2
>   **1 2 3 4 5 6**
>   Eq2: 3*x1+4*x2=6
>   Eq2: 3*x1+4*x2=6

Note that the bug exists only when typing the input on a single line with white spaces between the numbers, and does not exist when pressing the Enter key after each number.

Meaning, if the input comes one number at a time, the expected output is recieved correctly:

> This program solves a system of 2 linear equations Enter the
>   coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2
>
> **1**
>
> **2**
>
> **3**
>
> **4**
>
> **5**
>
> **6**
>
> Eq1: 1*x1+2*x2=5
>   Eq2: 3*x1+4*x2=6

Since it's hard to believe and hardly reproducible here is a screenshot:
[image]

What causes the difference when the input comes in a single line, separated by spaces, vs when it comes in separate lines, separated by enters?

How to have the desired output when the input comes in a single line format?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Are you able to reproduce it on `ideone.com` ?

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is the class you run was not compiled from the code your posted.

Comment: Code works, see: https://pastebin.com/deYnmbnV

Comment: @User8461 It works only if you press the Enter key after each number, if you're typing all of them on the same line with white spaces there's a bug.

Comment: unable to reproduce using eclipse, dos/command line or [ideone](https://ideone.com/HTILOC) (I don't use BlueJ)

Comment: Unable to reproduce in IntelliJ IDEA.  Typing the input `1 2 3 4 5 6` on one line returns the expected result

Comment: @noamsteiner We believe you.  We just also believe that there is a bug in the IDE that you're using that no one has ever heard of before ;)

Comment: @isapir XD I added this to make it clearer.
Unfortunately this is the IDE that the university requires to use at the course I'm taking...

Comment: @noamsteiner see update in my answer.  try to set the delimiter explicitly.

Comment: I could not reproduce with BlueJ 4.2.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: Works with OpenJDK 11.0.2,  BlueJ 4.2.0 and OpenJFX 11.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04:  https://imgur.com/a/XRmpU2E

Comment: and OpenJDK 1.8.0_181 with BlueJ 4.1.4 on Ubuntu works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug with your IDE.  Consider the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equations
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner("1 2 3 4 5 6");

        System.out.println("This program solves a system of 2 linear equations");
        System.out.println("Enter the coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2");

        int a11 = scan.nextInt();
        int a12 = scan.nextInt();
        int a21 = scan.nextInt();
        int a22 = scan.nextInt();
        int b1 = scan.nextInt();
        int b2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Eq1: "+ a11 +"*x1+"+ a12 +"*x2="+ b1);
        System.out.println("Eq2: "+ a21 +"*x1+"+ a22 +"*x2="+ b2);

    }
}
```

It's exactly the same code, with the exception that it does not rely on user input.  The input is separated by spaces, and the output is the expected:

```
This program solves a system of 2 linear equations
Enter the coefficients a11 a12 a21 a22 b1 b2
Eq1: 1*x1+2*x2=5
Eq2: 3*x1+4*x2=6
```

See [online Java compiler](http://tpcg.io/55lrxC)

Try to set the delimiter explicitly:

```
scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" |\n");
```